# How can I get all the NFT contract address via opensea API?

Tags: ethereum, nft, opensea

I just want to get all the contract address of all NFTs that are in the market, in particular I want to get the contract address for all ERC-721 tokens. From the opensea API documents, it seems that i can only get all the contract address of a specific owner..

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can query https://docs.opensea.io/reference/retrieving-collections to get all the collections by not passing in the `asset_owner` param. However, this API can only return 50K items and not more than that .

Comment: damn.. thank you tho, i didn't even get the api key from opensea, do you know how long will it take for them to process my request? thanks a lot!!

Comment: currently, they are revamping their system, so it's been hard to get a key. once they have it finished it should be easier. I would join the discord as they have been updating people there frequently